# How do i clone a repository from github to git gui ?

Tags: git, user-interface, github, sublimetext2

i have created a repository on Github called MessAbout, im trying to be able to teach my self how to put changes onto this repository by using sublime text 2. i thought that i would make the changes on sublime text2 then save the file, go to gitgui and commit the changes from there. Hopefully the changes will be stored on the Github repository called MessAbout. However i have no clue how to set this up whats so ever. I dont know whether to clone the repository and if so where the source location is or the target directory !!

If its possible to produce clear and concise instructions, that would be great so i can look back at it for future reference.

Thank you very much

hope you can help

Comment: this should help get you started: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are actually all Git-related and are not regarding Sublime Text in the first place. As suggested by @John, you should read [that article](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

In short

1. Clone the repository to whatever location pleases you
2. Open the folder (or just the files) in Sublime Text
3. After working, you can use your preferred method of the GitHub GUI client to commit changes

Another tip on the house, have a look at some of these [Git](https://sublime.wbond.net/browse/labels/git) packages for Sublime Text. Might save you from having to use the GitHub GUI client.